# Can't bind to 'opened' since it isn't a known property of 'md-sidenav'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

### I just update my angular material project to BETA.0.12

Before the update, all works nice but after the update, i don't know what I do wrong

And I have this error

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'opened' since it isn't a known property of 'md-sidenav'.
1. If 'md-sidenav' is an Angular component and it has 'opened' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
  <md-sidenav-container>

    <md-sidenav mode="side" [ERROR ->]opened="{{sidenavState | async }}">

      <!-- MENU LEFT -->
"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html@13:28
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
```

### This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';




// =============================================================================
//                                FIREBASE
// =============================================================================
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';



// =============================================================================
// ANGULAR MATERIAL 2
// =============================================================================
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatSidenav,
  MatGridList,
} from '@angular/material';

import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import 'hammerjs';
```

### this is my dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="main-container" fxLayout="column" fxFlex [class.dark-theme]="isDarkTheme" style="width:100vw;">

  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <app-admin-header></app-admin-header>


  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <!-- SIDENAV && SIDENAV CONTAINER -->
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <md-sidenav-container>

    <md-sidenav mode="side" opened="{{sidenavState | async }}">

      <!-- MENU LEFT -->
      <app-admin-nav-menu-left></app-admin-nav-menu-left>

    </md-sidenav>
```

### And i add material.module.ts in the src > app folder

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatSidenav
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSidenav
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSidenav
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

That is ok but i have this error

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MatSidenav' imported by the module 'MaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at compiler.es5.js:15398
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15381)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.es5.js:15323)
    at compiler.es5.js:15396
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15381)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26826)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26799)
```

Comment: Thnx You all for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `2.0.0-beta.12`, `md` prefix has been removed. See this [**CHANGELOG**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta12-marble-mustache-2017-10-05):

> All "md" prefixes have been removed. See the [**deprecation notice**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix) in the
>   beta.11 notes for more information.

Replace `md` prefix with `mat`. Your template needs to be:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened="{{sidenavState | async }}">

      <!-- MENU LEFT -->
      <app-admin-nav-menu-left></app-admin-nav-menu-left>

    </mat-sidenav>
```

Also, in your `material.module.ts`, you need to import `MatSidenavModule` instead of `MatSidenav`.

Comment: Small suggestion, `[opened]="sidenavState | async "` would look better to read and followed convention, already +1

Comment: Agreed @PankajParkar. I wanted to keep it like OP's example :)

Comment: ok now i have this erro Unexpected directive 'MatSidenav' imported by the module 'MaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: i make a module material.module.ts

Comment: in your `app.module.ts` or in `material.module.ts`, where you are importing material modules, replace `MatSidenav` with `MatSidenavModule`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `MatSidenavModule` you want to use the `mat-sidenav-container` as written in [their example here](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples). You're also trying to import the directive instead of the module. You need to use `MatSidenavModule` and not just `MatSidenav`. Be sure to import it both at the top of your app.module as well as declare it in your @ngModule imports section.

Comment: Thank you, bro, For your help